# (Linux) Get /dev/input/eventX from an attached USB device with PID:VID

Tags: c, linux, events, input, libusb

So my daemon will sit there and listen to udev, waiting for connect/disconnect events so it can notify the other thread to attach or stop reading from the /dev/input/eventX file.

Essentially, it's listening to a USB RFID scanner attached to the local system (which emulates a HID Keyboard).

Now I've got the /dev/input/eventX reading code going - but since I threaded it the UDEV thread crashes.

What is the best way of obtaining the correct /dev/input/eventX device from a known USB device (Like VID:PID)?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a udev rule that either runs a script to notify your program, or gives you a symlink to the device with a predictable name.  A quick search turned up [this page](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) explaining how to create rules.

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the same situation - a udevd rule to create a symlink to the event device if the VID:PID is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well the code crashing was a result of something else completely (vfprintf vs. fprintf) - anyway libudev as of version 172 has a nifty little function, that when enumerating devices it auto-binds the search (enumeration) to a single parent and returns only it's children:

```
udev_enumerate_add_match_parent()
```

I've already written the code that finds the hidraw device by VID/PID:

```
/sys/devices/pci000xyz/000.000.XYZ/usbX/X-Y
```

And I'm just waiting for that udev version to become streamlined with Ubuntu Natty, because then I'll just create a new enumeration and hand it the udev_device I found in the previous enum and get all it's children; Including the child device I'm after:

```
/sys/devices/pci000xyz/000.000.XYZ/usbX/X-Y/X-Y:A.B/input/inputX/eventY
```

In the mean time, I'll do as suggested and create a symlink - cheers Dmitri.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this file: `/proc/bus/input/devices`

Example line from the file:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1a2c Product=0c23 Version=0110
N: Name="USB USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1A2C:0C23.0015/input/input30
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdff3cfffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7
```

This function gets the event number from the device with the matching VID:PID:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void open_device (std::string device_vid, std::string device_pid)
{       
    try
    {
        std::ifstream file_input;
        std::size_t pos;
        std::string device_path, current_line, search_str, event_str;
        std::string device_list_file = "/proc/bus/input/devices";
        bool vid_pid_found = false;
        int fd = 0;
        bool debug = true;

        // 1. open device list file
        file_input.open(device_list_file.c_str());
        if (!file_input.is_open())
        {
            std::cerr << "file_input.open >> " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            throw -2;
        }

        // 2. search for first VID:PID and get event number
        search_str = "Vendor=" + device_vid + " Product=" + device_pid;
        while (getline(file_input, current_line))
        {
            if (!vid_pid_found)
            {
                pos = current_line.find(search_str, 0);
                if (pos != std::string::npos)
                {
                    vid_pid_found = true;
                    search_str = "event";
                }               
            }
            else
            {
                pos = current_line.find(search_str, 0);
                if (pos != std::string::npos)
                {
                    event_str = current_line.substr(pos);
                    // remove spaces from string
                    event_str.erase(std::remove(event_str.begin(), event_str.end(), ' '), event_str.end());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // 3.  build device path
        device_path = "/dev/input/" + event_str;
        if (debug) std::cout << "device_path = " << device_path << std::endl;   
        // 4.  connect to device
        fd = open (device_path.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "open >> errno = " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;       
            throw -3;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "e.what() = " << e.what() << std::endl;
        throw -1;
    }

    return;
}
```

The events are enumerated as they are plugged in.  `ls /dev/input` before and after unplugging a USB device will show different results.